# How to style TextField component from properties in Flash CS5 professional

Tags: flash-cs5

Hi
I am new to AS3.0, and what I am trying is to style Label, TextInput from the properties section show to the right.
But I couldnt find any alignment, font-size etc options.
How to style these components at design time, instead of AS3.0 code.

Answer (score 0):

In AS3.0 you can apply these styles to your components with some lines of code. This is an example from Adobe Help

```
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
tf.color = 0x333333; 
tf.font = "Georgia"; 
tf.size = 24; 
tf.align = "center"; 
tf.italic = true; 

textInput.setStyle("textFormat", tf);
```

More info here: http://goo.gl/dNCxe